# Slack webhook and direct/private messages

Tags: slack-api

I created a websocket-based Slack bot (that plays chess). In order to return a graphical representation of the board (so PNG instead of simple ASCII) I must use a webhook since normal messages cannot have attachments.

The interaction with the bot is through direct messages and I have 1 webhook. If I set the channel in the wehook to '@username' the message gets posted in that user 'slackbot' DM. But I want it to be posted in my bot's DM with that user.

How do I do that?

Or is there an alternative instead of a webhook?

Thanks.

Henry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Direct messages between bot and user**

If you want to use a bot-specific direct message channel instead of the general *slackbot* channel you need to open a direct message channel just as you would between any two users.

Open the direct message channel from your bot to a user with [`im.open`](https://api.slack.com/methods/im.open) (which will provide you with the channel ID). Then send the message to that channel ID, e.g. with `chat.postMessage`.
**Important**: Make sure you use the *bot access token* and not the general access token for all API calls.

**Method for sending messages**

I would recommend using the API method [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#channels) instead of the webhook. It gives you more options than a webhook and of course also supports attachments.